# How to get first image from json response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

How to get first image form the response from below response

`["147038089457a43b5e47d2a_job1.jpg",
"147038089457a43b5e48065_job2.jpg",
"147038089457a43b5e4829c_jobo_3.jpg"]`

I have tried ng-repeat is not working here.

Comment: First this is not a json. It's an array. get the first element of array as Array[0].

Comment: @Rakeschand Yes it is. it is a JSON array of strings

Comment: Please do show a [mcve] of what you tried with ng-repeat

Answer (score 0):

What you have mentioned in your question is an array.

```
 ["147038089457a43b5e47d2a_job1.jpg",
 "147038089457a43b5e48065_job2.jpg",
 "147038089457a43b5e4829c_jobo_3.jpg"]
```

Assuming this value is assigned to say a variable x, getting the first image from this response should be as simple as reading the first value `x[0]`.

```
<img src="x[0]" />
```

Comment: please help with detail code as example i am not able the pring first image inside ng repeat

Comment: The other answer is your "Detailed example with ng-repeat". Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

in you controller you would have...

```
$scope.amitImages = ["147038089457a43b5e47d2a_job1.jpg",
"147038089457a43b5e48065_job2.jpg",
"147038089457a43b5e4829c_jobo_3.jpg"]
```

If you want to do a repeat: In your view (html) you would have..

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="image in amitImages">
      <img ng-src="{{ image }}"/>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

If you JUST want the first image: In your view (html) you would have..

```
<img ng-src="{{ image[0] }}"/>
```

Comment: i am tried the same but not getting success MY Code example is {{topRatedJobs[0].job_images}}
   <tr ng-repeat="x in topRatedJobs.job_images">
       <td>
        <a href="{{ x[0] }}">Image1</a>
       </td>
   </tr>

Comment: @AmitKumar can you create a plunkr or fiddle of your problem.

Comment: Can you post more detailed example? also what topRatedJobs[0].job_images show you?

Comment: I think it's interesting that you are outputing topRatedJobs[0].job_images but are trying to repeat against  topRatedJobs.job_images. I suspect there is a disconnect somewhere, but need to see more code.

Comment: This is my response:

"DATA":[{"id":"13","job_title":"Need Guide For Tracking & Travelling"
,"job_images":"[\"147038089457a43b5e47d2a_job1.jpg\",\"147038089457a43b5e48065_job2.jpg\",\"147038089457a43b5e4829c_jobo_3
.jpg\"]","job_cost_max":"1000"}]

Comment: This is my code : <md-list-item class="md-3-line" dir-paginate="projectData in projectListData>
   <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">    
    <p ng-repeat="projectData.job_images in projectData.job_images">{{projectData.job_images[0]}}</p>
    <p>{{projectData.job_description}}</p>
   </div>             
  </md-list-item>

Comment: Amit, your projectData appears to be an array with one object and your job_images is a string. Can you change how you receive the data or is that not under  your control? Also, if you just want to show the first image why are you using an ng-repeat?

Comment: @AmitKumar are you still having trouble?